# Trying to record a screencast using ffmpeg but my mouse pointer is invisible

Tags: arch-linux, ffmpeg, screencasting

I'm trying to record a screencast using ffmpeg but my mouse pointer is invisible. What am I doing wrong? This is the command:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 -acodec pcm_s16le \
    -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 0 -threads 0 output.mkv
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used this command to capture my desktop and I did get the mouse included in my captured video:

```
$ ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1280x800 -i :0.0 -sameq out.mp4
```

[image: ss out.mp4 #1]

[image: ss out.mp4 #2]

Your exact command did not work for me, in terms of capturing any video, but this slightly modified version did, and it too was able to capture my mouse.

```
$ ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -f x11grab -r 25 -s 1280x800 -i :0.0 \
    -acodec pcm_s16le output.mkv
```

[image: ss output.mkv #1]

[image: ss output.mkv #2]

Answer (score 0):

It can depend on what cursor you are using. Cursor which works are:

- Breeze
- Breeze Snow
- DMZ (Black)
- DMZ (White)

I recorded video with them, changed them on video and this worked. However, when I have a 'default' cursor selected, which points to my own cursor I'm using it did not work. So, I wasted the whole recorded video to notice after all that it did not record my cursor. Sigh.

You can download new cursors from http://gnome-look.org/, namely from https://www.gnome-look.org/browse/cat/107/

In standard Linux X Configuration, you can put cursors to ~/.icons directory, in a subdirectory. Then, you can link to that directory using ln and naming the link 'default'. This way you whole system will be using the cursor from linked dir.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it is an old question but actual for me.

Changing cursors itself did not help in my case.

Screen recording with cursor works for me in case previously was opened and paused some video by mpv mediaplayer. My system is a Linux with openbox, lxqt and proprietary video driver.

My guessing is there are couple video interfaces and one of them is hardware accelerated. Hardware acceletared interface is derectly draw at screen without framebuffer, so it capturing is complicated. But when some other app occupaes accelerated inreface the system switch to regular that could be recorded with all details.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/442893)